# Implementing a Graph DFS in C++, pointers issue

Tags: c++, pointers, graph, depth-first-search

Sorry in advance, but some variable names and such have strange names, as I am not a native English speaker, I am also pretty new to programming.

So, I was doing a project with graphs topology sorting and similar, but I can't get DFS to work, I know that I am probably losing data because of usage of pointers in there(?), but I won't be using this adjacency list in my program any further anyway. The problem is just to get right result which in this case is when the vertex was entered (d[]) and left (f[]) but while in recursion my pointers go crazy, sometimes when I go back in recurrence (and apparently nothing else happens), I think at least because it's the first time I am using debugging function. I am sitting at this for like 8 hours already (not my first problem, but I managed to solve some, that's why code looks so ugly), and I was sitting with this debugger and didn't make any progress in over an hour, so I decided to ask, my first time using this website, I hope you can help me, and when I am a bit better I will definitely return the favor, here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
struct m_sasiedztwa
{
    int s;
    int** m;
    m_sasiedztwa(int a,float b) : s(a)
    {
        m = new int*[s];
        for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i)  m[i] = new int[s];
        for(int j=0; j<s; ++j)
            for(int k=0; k<s; ++k) if(j!=k) m[j][k]=((rand()%100)>(100*b))? 0 : 1; else m[j][k]=0;

    }
    ~m_sasiedztwa()
    {
        delete[] m;
    }
};
struct lista
{
    int key;
    lista *next;
};
struct l_nast
{
    int s;
    lista** arr;
    l_nast(int** m, int a) : s(a)
    {
        lista *curr,*prev;
        arr = new lista*[s];
        for(int i=0;i<s;++i)
        {
            arr[i] = new lista;
            curr = arr[i];
            prev=curr;
            prev->key=-1;
            for(int j=0;j<s;++j)
            {
                if(m[i][j]==1) {curr->next= new lista;curr->key=j;prev=curr;curr=curr->next;}

            }
            prev->next=nullptr;
        }

    }

~l_nast() {delete[] arr;}
};


//Here is the issue

bool *Nowy;
int c;
int* d,*f;
void DFS(int j,l_nast l_a)
{

            Nowy[j]=false;
            d[j]=c++;
            std::cout<<"Am I here yet..."<<j<<" "<<c<<std::endl;
                while((l_a.arr[j]!=nullptr)&&(l_a.arr[j]->key!=-1))
                {
                    std::cout<<"checking "<<(l_a.arr[j]->key)<<"...\n";
                    if(Nowy[l_a.arr[j]->key])
                    {

                    DFS(l_a.arr[j]->key,l_a);

                    }

                    if(l_a.arr[j]->next!=nullptr)                               //And I think this may be the problem, but I honestly don't know
                        l_a.arr[j]=l_a.arr[j]->next;
                            else break;
                }

            f[j]=c++;std::cout<<"Yohoo!"<<j<<" "<<c<<std::endl;

}




//Untill there

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    for(int q=5; q<6; q+=5)
    {

        m_sasiedztwa a = m_sasiedztwa(q, 0.2);
        m_sasiedztwa b = m_sasiedztwa(q, 0.4);

        l_nast l_a = l_nast(a.m,q);
        l_nast l_b = l_nast(b.m,q);
      /*
           for(int i=0; i<q; ++i)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<q; ++j)
                {
                    cout << a.m[i][j] << " ";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
            cout<<endl;
*/

        Nowy = new bool [q];
        d = new int [q];
        f = new int [q];
        c=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
        Nowy[i] = true;
/*for(int qq=0;qq<q;qq++)
  while((l_a.arr[qq]!=nullptr))
  {
      cout<<l_a.arr[qq]->key<<endl;
      l_a.arr[qq]=l_a.arr[qq]->next;

  }
*/

        for(int j=0;j<q;j++)
        {

            if(Nowy[j]) DFS(j,l_a);

        }



        a.~m_sasiedztwa();
        b.~m_sasiedztwa();

        l_a.~l_nast();
        l_b.~l_nast();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As I said it's not pretty, sorry for troubling you, again what I need help with is to get function DFS to properly result with d[] which is a table if integers which indicate when the vertex was visited, and f[] - table when the vertex was taken from the stack, just ordering 1,2,3..., the problem is - it breaks in the middle, sometimes it does like 7/10 sometimes just 2/10 and it breaks, of course, it will have to work for bigger graphs as well. The pointers are lost and it tries to check Nowy[some big number there] and program crashes.

Comment: `a.~m_sasiedztwa();` -- Why are you doing this and lines that look like this?  This is certainly incorrect.  Never call the destructor explicitly, unless you're doing things like *placement-new*, which you're certainly not doing.

Comment: in `~m_sasiedztwa()`, `delete[] m;` is insufficient. It only deletes `int** m`, which is the array of pointers to the inner dimension buffers, without deleting the inner dimension buffers. Big memory leak here. Consider instead making a simple 2D matrix class to handle the Rule of Three/Five for you. Eg: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op

Comment: Start [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dadc9234bd87dbdb).  That `struct` replaces your `struct` that is doing all sorts of dynamic allocation.  Note that there is no need for a destructor at all.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! This is most definietly better, I am sorry for incorrect usage of destructors, I didn't even use vectors yet, but it looks so much better. edit: I have a question, since I am new on the site, should I edit my post and implemented what you wrote here so others can read the code easier or should I leave it like is ?

Comment: You should leave the original post alone.

Comment: Oh, sorry then, I will make sure to leave it next time, thanks!

Comment: I solved the problem using a vector of forward list in my l_nast struct, what made it much easier, I think I will just delete this question since it doesn't really help anyone, or should I leave it?

Comment: I think you should leave it and post your answer.  Don't know if others will agree with me, but at the very least it will show persons the original code and the difference when C++ containers are used.  Also, I think you should revert your post back to your original code where you were not using vectors.

Comment: Ok, again thank you very much, you are a great person!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I used struct badly and made many mistakes, thanks to some comments I decided to use vector of vectors for adj matrix and vector of forward_list for adj list Here is what changed m_sasiedztwa struct

```
struct m_sasiedztwa
{
    int s;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m;
    m_sasiedztwa(int a,float b) : s(a), m(s, std::vector<int>(s,0))
    {
        for(int j=0; j<s; ++j)
            for(int k=0; k<s; ++k)
                if(j!=k)
                    m[j][k]=((rand()%100)>(100*b))? 0 : 1;
     }
};
```

l_nast struct:

```
struct l_nast
{
    int s;
    std::vector<std::forward_list<int>> arr;
    l_nast(std::vector<std::vector<int>> m, int a) : s(a), arr(s)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<s;++i)
        {
            auto it = arr[i].before_begin();
            for(int j=0;j<s;++j)
            {
                if(m[i][j]==1) {it = arr[i].emplace_after(it,j);}

            }
        }

    }

};
```

and the DFS:

```
void DFS(int j,l_nast l_a)
{

            Nowy[j]=false;
            d[j]=c++;
            std::cout<<"Visiting "<<j<<"as "<<c<<std::endl;
        auto x=l_a.arr[j].begin();

        for(auto& x: l_a.arr[j])
        {
                    if(Nowy[x])
                    {

                    DFS(x,l_a);

                    }

        }
            f[j]=c++;std::cout<<"Leaving "<<j<<"as "<<c<<std::endl;

}
```